# Real phone works but emulator can't be run in intellij idea when I work on an Android project

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-emulator

I'm trying to learn to write an Android App on intellij idea.And I've already downloaded JDK and SDK and have set them.However,when I run the program(just "hello world") on android emulator,it can be opened but always black screen(when I press the button,no response).But I can run my program on my real phone.So how to let the emulator work?

I have already turned down the resolution ratio and have checked that my cpu is vertualized,but that didn't work.

Where is the problem?And how to solve that?

Comment: If you are fine with a real device testing then its ok ... I recommend physical device testing However if you want to test it on emulator then you need to setup emulator first Check out this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

Comment: Thank you.It seems that downloading android emulator on intellij idea is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I have solved the problem...I didn't download Android emulator on intellij idea.